# Generic model extension with type restriction is not called

Tags: ios, swift, generics, response

I have this generic `Response` which has a generic decodable element of type `T`. Adding an extension for a specific type is not getting called which is obvious. Is there any logic reason for this? Given that this is added in SPM.

**Response.swift**

```swift
struct Response<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let status: Bool
    let data: T
    let message: String
    
    // MARK: CodingKeys
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case data
        case message
    }
}

// This never gets called for type `EmptyResponse`
extension Response where T == EmptyResponse {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.status = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
        self.message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        self.data = EmptyResponse()
    }
}

extension Response {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.status = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
        self.message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        self.data = try (EmptyResponse() as? T) ?? container.decode(T.self, forKey: .data)
    }
}
```

**EmptyResponse.swift**

```swift
public struct EmptyResponse: Decodable {
}
```

As a workaround, casting is working fine

```swift
extension Response {
    ...
        self.data = try (EmptyResponse() as? T) ?? container.decode(T.self, forKey: .data)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well this is just how Swift is designed. Allowing you to do something like this would require a lot of work. Accept it and move on. IMO, checking `T.self == EmptyResponse.self` is more readable.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, I think there's something to make it work since the extensions to generic `Foundation` models like Sequence or Collection which has Element type is working

**Example**
```swift
extension Sequence where Element == Int { }
```

Comment: The problem here is not about `where Element == Int`. The problem is that you want `Response` to have multiple conformances to the same protocol. You want `Response<EmptyResponse>` to conform to `Decodable` one way, and `Response<EverythingElse>` to conform to `Decodable` *another way*. This is not supported.

Comment: This is clear now, Thanks Sweeper! 